# Centre TikZ figure vertically (\vspace*{fill} does not work)

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikz-pic

I want to print a lined page with a gap in the middle that should be in the centre of the page vertically. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=320mm, paperwidth=450mm, top=0pt, bottom=0pt]{geometry} %Top=-10pt to start right at the top
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\linegap}{5}
\newcommand{\linenumber}{19} %Off by one error, actual lines are one more then the one here
\newcommand{\spacing}{25}
\newcommand{\nextparagraphstart}{\the\numexpr\linegap*\linenumber+\spacing}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
[
        remember picture,
        overlay,
        every path/.style={
            line width=0.2mm,
        },
    ]
        \foreach \y in {0, \linegap, ..., \the\numexpr\linegap *\linenumber} {
            \coordinate (key) at (0, -\y mm);
            \draw (current page.west |- key) -- (current page.east |- key);
        }

        \foreach \y in {\nextparagraphstart, \the\numexpr\nextparagraphstart+\linegap, ..., \the\numexpr\nextparagraphstart+\linegap*\linenumber} {
            \coordinate (key) at (0, -\y mm);
            \draw (current page.west |- key) -- (current page.east |- key);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have looked at similar questions and that suggest `\vfill` before and after figure which did not change anything. Have used `\null` and ~ before the `\vfill` and it also did nothing. I have also tried `\vspace*{\fill}` before and after the figure and it also didn't change anything.
Is the coordinate command in TikZ not relative to the figure and instead specific for the page or is it some other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using options `remember picture, overlay` and page node `current page`, the tikz picture is drawn at absolute positions of the current page, irrelevant to the surrounding spacing commands like `\vspace`. Thus you should draw lines at the positions you want them on.

```tex
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=320mm, paperwidth=450mm, top=0pt, bottom=0pt]{geometry} %Top=-10pt to start right at the top
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\linegap}  \setlength{\linegap}{5mm}
\newlength{\spacing}  \setlength{\spacing}{25mm}
\newlength{\currentyshift}

\newcommand{\linenumber}{19} %Off by one error, actual lines are one more then the one here


\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    every path/.style={
        line width=0.2mm,
    },
]
    \setlength{\currentyshift}{\dimexpr.5\spacing -\linegap\relax}
    \foreach \y in {0, 1, ..., \linenumber} {
        \global\advance\currentyshift by \linegap
        % or the local assignment
        % \addtolength{\currentyshift}{\y\linegap}
        \draw
          ([yshift= \currentyshift]current page.west) -- 
          ([yshift= \currentyshift]current page.east)
          ([yshift=-\currentyshift]current page.west) -- 
          ([yshift=-\currentyshift]current page.east);
    }
    
    % helper,
    \draw[cyan!50, thick]
      % mark the center of page
      (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east)
      (current page.north east) -- (current page.south west)
      % visualize the spacing
      ([shift={( .5\spacing,  .5\spacing)}]current page) rectangle
      ([shift={(-.5\spacing, -.5\spacing)}]current page);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing .. something like this?

[image]

(red line is on vertical middle of page, blue box size is equal to `\spacing` in mm)

**Edit:**
Your code is significantly simplified. Now it consider your comment (distance between line groups should equal to `\spacing`).

In comparison to original solution is now one loop less and for calculation of half of the `\spacing` is employed `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

I hope that now I correctly figured out what mean some defined commands (still unclear what in which units is `\linegap`) .

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=320mm, paperwidth=450mm, 
            top=0pt, bottom=0pt]{geometry}
   \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\linegap}{5}
\newcommand{\linenumber}{19} %Off by one error, actual lines are one more then the one here
\newcommand{\spacing}{25}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\halfspacing}{\spacing/2}
    \draw[red] (current page.west) -- node[draw=blue, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=\spacing mm] {} ++ (\paperwidth,0);

\foreach \y in {0,1, ...,\linenumber}
{
\draw   ([yshift= +\halfspacing mm] $(current page.west)+(0,\y*\linegap/10)$) -- ++ (\paperwidth,0);
\draw   ([yshift= -\halfspacing mm] $(current page.west)-(0,\y*\linegap/10)$) -- ++ (\paperwidth,0);
}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the centering, however the spacing is used for the total space between the bottom of the first group of lines and the top of the second group so it should be divided by 2, how would this be done? Just using \spacing/2  with or without parentheses does not work.

Comment: @DragonStaty, sorry, but question is not very clear about this. Considering your comment, I correct code in answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `tikzpicture` [overlay] takes up almost no space (equivalent to `\hbox{}`).  You need to fill the text area with blank space.  Otherwise any following text will simply write over the `tikzpicture`.

I didn't try to fix your `foreach` loops.  This simply locates the center of the page (and the center of the text area).  You can add your lines relative to that starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
\makebox[\textwidth]{center of text area}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
[
        remember picture,
        overlay,
        every path/.style={
            line width=0.2mm,
        },
    ]
      \node[text=red] at (current page.center) {center of page};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```